# iOS Storing IAP flag in Keychain so it's secure

Tags: ios, security, keychain

I'm implementing Keychain to store a flag for a successful IAP. I had some questions about security for this since I don't know which objects are able to be seen by someone cracking my app.

```
KeychainItemWrapper *wrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"theKey" accessGroup:nil];

[wrapper setObject:@"password" forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
```

If I write in a password in the `setObjectForKey` method above, would someone be able to see that password literal or variable in the executable? When I set this, isn't it "naked" and easy for the nefarious hacker to grab?

Comment: Yes it's naked, if the hacker does know a little about google :). You would better not store "naked" password in anywhere, hashing or even encrypting the password could give you more time, before hacker gets your password.

Comment: How do I do that since at some point it has to be naked? Keeping in mind that I have to store some Boolean flag to know if user made IAP and not storing password for auth.

Comment: @FahriAzimov I just looked and saw that SKPaymentTransaction has a `transactionIdentifier` property that is a unique string. What do you think of using this as a password? I don't believe it gets generated until the SKPaymentTransaction is returned successful.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to protect against? The security issue with IAPs comes from jailbreaked devices, and on those, you can't trust much of anything. Your only option is to use (secure) server-side validation of the receipt.

Comment: @jcaron is there a link you can provide that explains server-side validation? And basically I want a boolean flag stored that shows that it was purchased.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

Comment: Once you've validated, just store it in NSUserDefaults. Unless someone specifically hacks your app (rather than all IAPs as is generally the case), this will be more than enough. Or you could store the result on your server, get that info every time the app is launched, and store in a singleton instance. There are probably a hundred different ways of doing it, but it really revolves around "What exactly are you trying to protect against?"

Answer (score 0):

Your security concern is that a user will alter a file so that instead of reading "IAP not yet purchased" it now reads "IAP has been purchased".  The easiest way of avoiding this is to indicate that the IAP has been purchased by storing the user's identifierForVendor in a file variable, even NSUserDefault.  The identifierForVendor is different for each device.  If you want added security then create a hash of the identifierForVendor and a secret string that only you know like "my secret".